# Drupal site not loading any CSS/JS/Images

Tags: migrations

I've been trying to migrate my site from my local to GoDaddy server. I've done it so many times before and it's worked fine but this time I can't quite figure out what's wrong.

My steps on migrating the site:

1. Clear cache
2. Export DB
3. Create DB on server and import local DB
4. Upload Files (tar zip)
5. Change settings file

As I say, that's worked for me this whole time but now the site and content loads up fine but no styles, no images, no js. If I inspect the page it seems all of those files have a **403 forbidden error.**

[image]

I noticed that even the Drupal menu and other Drupal CMS styles aren't loading up either so maybe that could be important in finding a solution?

Comment: Check your path in admin/config/media/file-system

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the problem, it was all to do with file/folder permissions. So I did some reading and I learnt that it's recommended that folders are 755 and files are 644 (with the exception of htacces)

So I went and made those changes to files/folders and it all seems to work fine.